# Randomly sample table cells - equal N across rows and columns

Tags: r, random, sampling

I plan to have 12 people answer 300 questions.  Each subject will answer 100 questions, and each question answered by 4 subjects.

For various reasons, the assignment must be random.  Here is how I approach this but am open to any ideas.

I created a blank 300*12 data frame (300 rows named by question ids and 12 columns for subjects).  For each subject column, randomly sample 100 rows and put "1" in the 100 cells.  As a result, I can make sure each subject is assigned to 100 questions randomly, but not all questions get answered by exactly 4 subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is a problem that comes up in community ecology (generating "null communities" with observed marginals), you can do it with the `permatswap()` function in the `vegan` package.

Generate a binary matrix (non-random) matrix with desired marginals:

```
basemat <- matrix(0,nrow=300,ncol=12)
nq <- 100  ## number of questions
qs <- ncol(basemat)*nq/nrow(basemat) ## q per subject
for (i in 1:ncol(basemat)) {
    basemat[1:100+(nq*((i-1) %/% qs)),i]  <- 1
}
## check margins
all(rowSums(basemat)==qs)
all(colSums(basemat)==nq)
```

Now swap:

```
pp <- permatswap(basemat,times=1)
pp$perm[[1]]  ## extract matrix
```

This generates one random binary matrix with the specified margins. This is a fairly difficult computational problem: depending on how important the properties of the randomization are to you, you should at least use `image()` on the result to check visually that it looks scrambled, and strongly consider digging through the `?permatswap` and `?make.commsim` help pages from `vegan` to get an understanding of some of the technical issues ...

You might also be able to find a solution by searching the literature on *Latin square* designs. (In R: `library("sos"); findFn("latin square")`)

Comment: This is exactly what I desperately wanted! Thank you!  Will also dig into the technical issues as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

@ben-bolker's answer is way more elegant, but I thought I'd post my answer since I coded it up already.  The idea is to mimic what one might do if one were to do the assignment manually. We create a pool of numbers from 1 to 300, where each number is repeated 4 times. Then, Subject 1 draws 100 numbers without replacement, re-drawing if a number is drawn that Subject 1 has already drawn. Then Subject 2 does the same, and we repeat all the way to Subject 11.

```
N <- 12
K <- 100
set.seed(123)

pool <- rep(1:300, each = 4)
assignments <- vector("list", N)
for (i in 1:(N - 1)) {
  for (j in 1:K) {
    repeat {
      draw <- sample(pool, 1)
      if (!(draw %in% assignments[[i]]))
        break
    }
    assignments[[i]] <- c(assignments[[i]], draw)
    pool <- pool[-which(pool == draw)[1]]
  }
}
assignments[[N]] <- pool
```

Subject 12 ends up with the remaining 100 numbers. It is likely that there are duplicates in these 100 numbers.  For each duplicate, Subject 12 goes first to Subject 1. If Subject 1 doesn't already have that number, Subject 12 swaps the number with Subject 1 for a randomly drawn number that Subject 12 doesn't already have.  If Subject 1 already has the number, Subject 12 goes instead to Subject 2 (and if necessary Subject 3, Subject 4, etc.)

```
dupes <- assignments[[N]][duplicated(assignments[[N]])]
for (k in 1:length(dupes)) {
  fixed <- FALSE
  xx <- dupes[k]
  counter <- 1
  while (!fixed) {
    if (!(xx %in% assignments[[counter]])) {
      swap <- setdiff(assignments[[counter]], assignments[[N]])[1]
      assignments[[N]][which(assignments[[N]] == xx)[1]] <- swap
      assignments[[counter]][which(assignments[[counter]] == swap)[1]] <- xx
      cat(sprintf("Swapped %d for %d with Subject %d\n", xx, swap, counter))
      fixed <- TRUE
    } else {
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
}
```

We can verify that we get the correct marginal sums:

```
mat <- matrix(0, nc = 300, nr = 12)
for (i in 1:N) {
  for (j in 1:K) {
    mat[i, assignments[[i]][j]] <- 1
  }
}
unique(rowSums(mat))
# [1] 100
unique(colSums(mat))
# [1] 4
```

Comment: Before posting here, I coded it up all the way to Subject 11 just as you did, and then went about dealing with Subject 12 manually in a spreadsheet.  Your answer works perfect as well and saved me a ton of time.  Thank you!